# Проблема при фильтрации данных с БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, запрос

Всех приветствую.
Есть проблема при фильтрации.
Пробую её добавить в БД.
Выдаёт следующую ошибку, скорее всего и на кириллицу ругается, только не пойму как лучше исправить
Сам код кнопки, по которой начинается запрос:

```
private void button_PrimenFiltrVedom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string txt = "";
if (TextBox_Ved_KodSkl.Text != "")
{

txt = "Код склада LIKE '%" + TextBox_Ved_KodSkl.Text + "%'";

}
if (TextBox_Ved_KodTov.Text != "")
{

if (txt != "")
txt = txt + "AND";
txt = txt + "Код товара LIKE '%" + TextBox_Ved_KodTov.Text + "%'";

}
if (TextBox_Ved_KodZakazhika.Text != "")
{
if (txt != "")
txt = txt + "AND";
txt = txt + "Код заказчика LIKE '%" + TextBox_Ved_KodZakazhika.Text + "%'";
}
if (TextBox_Ved_SummaBolee.Text != "")
{

if (txt != "")
txt = txt + "AND";
txt = txt + "Сумма поставки >'%" + TextBox_Ved_SummaBolee.Text + "%'";

}
if (TextBox_Ved_SummaMenee.Text != "")
{

if (txt != "")
txt = txt + "AND";
txt = txt + "Сумма поставки < '%" + TextBox_Ved_SummaMenee.Text + "%'";

}
bindingSourceПоставка_продукции.Filter = txt;
}
```

Так же картинки данных и ошибки, которые ввожу:
[image: Код склада поиск]
[image: Ошибка по фильтрации]
Так же не до конца уверен, как лучше подстроить и по времени и по сумме, больше и меньше.
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Внёс следующие изменения, добавив в '' названия столбцов, но данные теперь вообще не выводит, подскажите, что не так и как можно по дате ещё добавить фильтрацию в код, пожалуйста? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA9u9.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/i37JU.jpg

Comment: как ваш результирующий SQL запрос выглядит и как он должен выглядеть?

Comment: Я сам код же приложил или что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Данную ошибку исправил, поместил название столбцов в ' ', но запрос почем-то не работает и после этого.

Comment: я имею ввиду итоговый звпрос, который уже едет в БД как результат выполнения вашего кода

Comment: какая у вас база данных? Вы можете каким то способом к ней поделючиться и выполнять SQL запросы руками в ней, через какой то уже готовый инструмент?

Comment: БД я создал в Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, и потом подключил в VS её, занёс данные и по ним думал фильтр сделать нужный.

Comment: вы можете в MS SQL Management Studio руками написать сначала запрос, который вы хотите генерировать кодом? Со всеми фильтрами или что вам надо. Написать, выполнить и убедиться, что он работает.

Comment: Можно конечно попробовать, но я думал в коде что-то не так и подскажут. Из-за этого написал.

Comment: В коде у вас не так все, но прежде чем я вам об этом расскажу, я хочу знать какой текст SQL конкретно вам надо от этого кода получить